# how could I do some async thing in node-orm2's each function?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous, node-orm2

I have some code like this:

```
req.models.order.find({})
  .each(function(order){
    req.models.food.find({orderId: order.id}{
      //...
      order.foods = ['...'];
      return order;
    })
  })
  .get(function(order){
    //the orders have no 'foods' attribute
  })
```

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use [associations](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2#associations) (like one-to-many or many-to-many), which would be the most preferable path to go.

The other way to do it (maybe not too pro, but surely works) is to make a counter initialized with number of returned orders, decrementing with every next "each" iteration, and eventually firing "get" inside the "each" when the counter reaches 0.